# Can't access instance after setting up iptables rules

Tags: iptables, bash, shell-scripting

I'm trying to setup some rules to block all ports except 21 and 22 on TCP (SSH and FTP). But when I try to run this script I get locked out of my instance and can't access it. This is the script:

```
# Flush the FW Rules 
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Block all traffic
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow FTP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

In script it sets up both incoming and outgoing requests for SSH and FTP but why can't I access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. For rules in the `OUTPUT` chain you should specify the source port match (`--sport`), not the destination port (`--dport`).
2. Anyway `DROP` policy in the `OUTPUT` chain isn't a common practice.
3. Read the iptables tutorial and example rule sets.
4. To avoid of lost of the connection, better use `iptables-save` and `iptables-apply` tools.

Comment: Works great after changing the flag --dport to --sport instead. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You should set up state tracking, and lose the `-A OUTPUT ... -j ACCEPT` lines.

```
IPTABLES -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
IPTABLES -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
IPTABLES -I OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

It's good to see you are using explicit egress filtering, but it's more work to implement.